# What program to use to customise or edit Vtiger

Tags: vtiger

I am new to Vtiger CRM. Recently just installed Vtiger 6.0 that comes free from mojo marketplace that comes together in ipage hosting.

But i would like to edit some parts in the vtiger CRM (etc: Login page, add some modules, creating a new customise invoice template).

I went through some advice online in here. But i cannot find the file locations mentioned and don't understand do they do it. Can someone please help to advice me?

Answer (score 1):

have to consider php hardcoding of the system files, and some additional plugin.

- To edit the Login page have to modify the Modules/Users/view/login.php
- To add modules you can consider the installation of this plugin http://www.technokrafts.com/technokrafts-shop/vtiger-crm-addons/vtiger-module-builder/
  it's free
- To customize the Invoice template, you have to consider the installation of PDF Maker plugin:
  https://marketplace.vtiger.com/app/listings?id=14